# how to append multiple quill editor with angular and js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, quill

I would like append multiple quill editor into a div with the append.

The goal is to append the suitable template when the post type is 1 or 2 and append the quill editor with the content for each of theses posts

But I don't know how to generate multiple quill editor, I tried this:

```js
    $http.post("/getwallpost", reqGetPost).then(function(response) {
         
        response.data.forEach(function(item) {

            if(item.type_id == 1) {
                var youp = "#" + item.id
                wallcontent.append("<div id='" + item.id + "'></div>");
                new Quill("#" + item.id, optionwall).setContents(JSON.parse(item.content));
                
            } else if(item.type_id == 2) {
                wallcontent.append('<div class="myArticles">This is article</div>');
            }
        });
       
    });
```

```html
 <div id="wallcontent">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's ok, it works.

I used number for html id. I had to use chars like "#sqjdofjez" + item.id and not only "#5"